# Why does my class not work properly in a Java HashSet?

Tags: java, collections, hashset

I am working on a project that involves me using a `HashSet` of a class I made, which I will name `Test`. I defined the stated `HashSet` like so:

```
HashSet<Test> t = new HashSet<Test>();
t.add(new Test("asdf", 1));
t.add(new Test("hello", 2));
t.add(new Test("hello", 3));
```

I tried using

```
t.contains(new Test("asdf", 1));
```

but it returns `false`. However, when I use a `HashSet<Character>` it seems to work fine. I tried overriding the previous `equals` declaration, but it didn't work. I tried leaving `equals` alone, but i still got `false`. I need to know what i am doing wrong?

also, i did not edit the hash function, i only changed Test.equals(Object o). It's a simple project and since the java documentation states that it uses o.equals(this), i thought i would not have to.

Comment: Can you post the your Test class, specifcally the equals and hashCode methods.

Comment: `HashSet.add` takes only one argument, not two. And your second code block contains a syntax error.

Comment: Also, the point of HashSet<Test> is that your HashSet will contains instances of Test. So it should be 
t.add(new Test("asdf", 1));

Comment: Please post compileable code examples.

Comment: The mystery to me is how does this work for `HashSet<Character>` matter of fact how does it even compile much less work.

Comment: i'm really, really, really sorry. i forgot to use a constructor in t.add. that was not intentionally typed, but i made the proper revisions already. i'm sorry for the hassle to those that answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have to overload the hashCode() method as well.

Comment: That should be "will", not "might".

Answer (score 4):

`HashSet.add(Object data)` is not equal to `HashSet.add(new Test(String, int))`

Try to use `HashSet.add(new Test("asdf", 1));`. And make overrides from the `hashCode()` method. Does your code compile?

Answer (score 3):

Your code will not even compile...

HashSet does not have an add() method which accepts two arguments.

If you mean

```
t.add(new Test("asdf", 1));
```

in stead of

```
t.add("asdf", 1);
```

be sure the hashcode and equals method of the Test class are implemented properly, as said before.

Answer (score 2):

Internally a hashtable will use Object#hashCode(), to hash and bucket your objects, and Object#equals() to test for equality if there are hashCode clashes. You need to ensure that your Test class provides suitable implementations (overrrides)  these, in your case to test for string equality, otherwise the default Object#equals() method will use the objects instance identity (ref id). See [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2002-06/01-qa-0621-hashtable.html) for a tutorial on this topic.